# Why is an iterator moved in this function?

Tags: rust, iterator, ownership

I want to get a function to accept two `Iterator`s and a callback and process as follows:

```
fn for_xy<I: Iterator<Item = usize>, F>(ix: I, iy: I, f: F)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = usize>,
    F: FnMut(usize, usize) -> (),
{
    for x in ix {
        for y in iy {
            f(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `iy`
   --> src/lib.rs:7:18
    |
1   | fn for_xy<I: Iterator<Item = usize>, F>(ix: I, iy: I, f: F)
    |                                                -- move occurs because `iy` has type `I`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
7   |         for y in iy {
    |                  ^^ `iy` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`, in previous iteration of loop
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `iy`
help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop
    |
7   |         for y in &iy {
    |                  ^^^
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
3   |     I: Iterator<Item = usize> + Copy,
    |                               ^^^^^^
```

How can I correct this program?

Comment: An iterator can be iterated only once. Your code iterates `iy` many times, once for each item in `ix`. I suggest accepting slices instead of iterators, since they can be iterated over many times

Comment: Another way might be to require `Iterator<item = &usize>` and use `iy.copied()`.

Comment: If your iterator is Copy, you might be able to solve it by demanding I: Copy.

Comment: You can [request the iterator to be `Clone`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6368b7de67767e9277908777721c3316) - many iterators (including those that iterate over `Vec`s) are.

Comment: I edited the question to contain the actual error that rustc currently gives for the code you provided (there's also an error about `f` not being `mut`, but that doesn't seem relevant). If you're using an IDE or something that shows you abridged errors, like what was originally in the question, you should stop using that IDE. Rust's errors are usually very descriptive (even if the particular suggestions in this error message don't actually help).

Comment: Requesting `Clone` (and iterating over `iy.clone()`) is better than `Copy`, because more types implement `Clone`. One such type is `std::ops::Range` which seems a likely candidate to be passed to a function like this.

Comment: @Cerberus that still doesn't work because you can still only execute the iterator once. You'd have to collect all of the `&usize` values into a vector or something.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a `for` loop, the iterable argument you pass is *moved* into the `for` loop; after iteration completes, the iterator is dropped. If you want to make the iterator reusable, the typical way is to add a `Clone` bound. Additionally, in principle you're going to have the same problem (in reverse) with you `x` items from the `ix` iterator: because you're reusing them with each iteration of the `iy` loop, you need to ensure they can be cloned or copied. This problem doesn't happen with `usize`, which is copyable, but a more generic version will need to include a `Clone` or `Copy` bound on `ix::Item`:

```rust
fn for_xy<X, Y, F>(ix: X, iy: Y, f: F)
where
    X: Iterator,
    X::Item: Clone,
    Y: Iterator + Clone,
    F: FnMut(X::Item, Y::Item)
) -> {
    for x in ix {
        for y in iy.clone() {
            f(x.clone(), y)
        }
    }
}
```

In practice, most iterators you encounter in Rust are cheaply cloneable. The colletion iterators (such as `Vec::iter`, `HashMap::iter`) contain simple references to the underlying collection, and most iterator adapters (`map`, `filter`, etc) are cheaply cloneable so long as the iterator being adapted is as well.